# Can't generate 3 line graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am not going to stretch this, will come straight to the point, this is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def fifo_page_replacement(num_frames, reference_string):
    frame_list = []  # List to store the currently allocated page frames
    fault_count = 0  # Counter for page faults

    for page in reference_string:
        if page not in frame_list:
            fault_count += 1

            if len(frame_list) == num_frames:
                # Remove the oldest page from the page frames
                frame_list.pop(0)

            # Add the new page to the page frames
            frame_list.append(page)

    return fault_count


# Sample data
# Sample data
num_frames = 3  # Number of page frames to test
reference_string = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    2,
    1,
    5,
    6,
    2,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    7,
    6,
    3,
    2,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    6,
]  # Reference string

# Generate x-axis values
x_values_1 = np.arange(1, num_frames + 1)
x_values_2 = np.arange(1, num_frames + 2)
x_values_3 = np.arange(1, num_frames + 3)

# Calculate page faults using FIFO algorithm for the given number of frames
page_faults_1 = [fifo_page_replacement(frame, reference_string) for frame in x_values_1]
page_faults_2 = [fifo_page_replacement(frame, reference_string) for frame in x_values_2]
page_faults_3 = [fifo_page_replacement(frame, reference_string) for frame in x_values_3]

# Plotting
plt.plot(x_values_1, page_faults_1, label="Line 1", marker="o")
plt.plot(x_values_2, page_faults_2, label="Line 2", marker="o")
plt.plot(x_values_3, page_faults_3, label="Line 3", marker="o")

plt.xlabel("Number of Page Frames")
plt.ylabel("Number of Page Faults")
plt.title("FIFO Page Replacement Algorithm")
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

I want a three line graph, basically three different plots in a single graph. `fifo_paging_algorithm` is returning values as expected. Also I don't want different graphs for three different plots, just one graph.

I am expecting the above results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine, your data is bad and thus you only get line 3 which shadows the other data which are subsets of line 3. If you give `matplotlib` distinct data your code works just fine.

Changing your code to generate the data to this:

```
page_faults_1 = [fifo_page_replacement(frame, reference_string) for frame in x_values_1]
page_faults_2 = [fifo_page_replacement(frame, reference_string) * 2 for frame in x_values_2]
page_faults_3 = [fifo_page_replacement(frame, reference_string) * 3 for frame in x_values_3]
```

Produces the desired 3 lines in one plot:
[image]